# Linq DataContext and isolation levels

Tags: linq-to-sql

With no special settings added, how does linq to sql datacontext behave in case of a single submitchanges() at the end? My db is on mssql server

I am confused as to at what time the transaction starts exactly. Consider the following pseudo EXAGGERATED code:

```
DataContext dc= new DataContext();
Thread.Sleep(10 min);
var rs = from a in dc.myTable Where.. select r;
.............
.............
.............
use rs //but do nothing to edit myTable.May be loop over it(?) to force execution
.............
.............
Thread.Sleep(10 min);
//read again, same criteria as before
rs = from a in dc.myTable Where.. select r;
.............
.............

dc.SubmitChanges()
```

1. If I do not explicitly change any settings anywhere, both code and db. will my rs return same results the second time even if someone else inserted(and committed) new rows into the table that match my selection criteria?
2. When/At what time exactly does linq's implicit transaction start? Right when DataContext is instantiated? Or depending on what we do (or don't do) with DataContext, when dc.SubmitChanges() is called?

Answer (score 0):

1. When you do not explicitly start a transaction at a specific isolation level, your reads happen outside of a transaction and run at the default isolation level, which I believe is Read Committed. If in between execution of the two queries some other user inserts other records that match your criteria, they will show up in the second query's results.
2. Implicit transactions are started just before the actual data is submitted to the database and committed right after. If you call `SubmitChanges` multiple times, there will be a transaction for every call.

With regards to the first question: if you *do* run the queries inside a transaction, be careful which isolation level you use, and how the tables' locking escalation policies are set. By default, if you use `using (var scope = new TransactionScope())`, your first query will result in the table being locked. Other users wishing to insert records will end up waiting for a while and having their operation rejected because of a time-out. Read more about isolation levels [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.isolationlevel.aspx).